# Vertical Alignment of text in a table cell

Tags: html, css

Here's a portion of my table (it's a form):

[image]

Those are just two `<td>`'s in a `<tr>`. I'm trying to get **Description** up top, to the top of the table cell, rather than resting on the bottom.

How can I do that?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` for centering, what i used inside table <td> cell.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
td.description {vertical-align: top;}
```

where `description` is the class name of the `td` with that text in it

```css
td.description {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<td class="description">Description</td>
```

OR inline (yuk!)

```html
<td style="vertical-align: top;">Description</td>
```

Comment: this doesn´t work for me :( maybe because the Description td has one line of text and the 2nd td has many?

Comment: oops, false alarm, my problem was that I was incorrectly setting a padding on the TD that I was trying to align

Answer (score 10):

Try

```css
td.description {
  line-height: 15px
}
```

```html
<td class="description">Description</td>
```

Set the line-height value to the desired value.

Comment: I like this alternative approach. It gives you a different kind of control that may be useful when combining other CSS styling etc.

Answer (score 9):

`valign="top"` should do the work.

```html
<tr>
  <td valign="top">Description</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The `valign` attribute is being deprecated in HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_tr_valign.asp

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Bootstrap, please add the following customised style setting for your table:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th {
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but solved it by using `!important`. I forgot about the inheritance in `CSS`. Just a tip to check first.

Answer (score 2):

CSS {vertical-align: top;} or html Attribute {valign="top"}

```css
.table td, 
.table th {
    border: 1px solid #161b21;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    
    /* style for table */
}

.table-body-text {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th valign="top">Title 1</th>
      <th valign="top">Title 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-body-text">text</td>
      <td class="table-body-text">text</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

For table vertical-align we have 2 options.

1. is to use css {vertical-align: top;}

> 

2. another way is to user attribute "valign" and the property should be "top" {valign="top"}

Comment: `valign` is obsolete since HTML5 and shouldn't be used anymore (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-valign)

Answer (score 1):

Just add vertical-align:top for first td alone needed not for all td.

```css
tr>td:first-child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>more text</td>
</tr>
```