# Table column contents not vertically aligned

Tags: html, html-table, vertical-alignment, tablelayout

I'm having issues with the contents of one column not vertically aligning with the next column. I'm working in HTML. I'm not familiar with CSS aside from a couple things I've copied. First column has 3 images, second column has a table within it with multiple images. The 3 images of the first column are aligned halfway down the contents of the next column. I can't get the first column images to align at the top like the others. The page is: http://www.fredstrainshop.com/ho.html.
Code is probably too long to post here but I can if you want. Thanks!

Comment: where are the closing tags for `<td>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Alignment of text in a table cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943166/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-cell)

Comment: If you question is answered please select any of the answers as [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you are trying to align first column content as the second, if so, Try by adding following CSS property to your first `<td>` tag.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `style="vertical-align:baseline"` or `style="vertical-align:top"` in first `<td>` for your table :

```
<td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
<a href="storemp4.jpg">
<img class="IMG2" src="storemp3.jpg">
</a><br><br><a href="storemp5.jpg">
<img class="IMG2" src="storemp4.jpg">
</a><br><br><a href="storemp6.jpg">
<img class="IMG2" src="storemp5.jpg">
</a><table cellspacing="25" cellpadding="25" border="0">
</table>
</td>
```

Also remove extra tables and the images which are not available.

**Note:** Keep your table structure simple by using appropriate `<tr>` and `<td>` remove nested tables if they are not required.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much and for everyone's help!

Comment: Please mark any of the answers as answered.

Answer (score 0):

When I check your page after http://www.fredstrainshop.com/ho.html after this element:

`<a href="woodland-scenics.jpg"><img class="IMG1" src="woodland-scenics.jpg"></a>`

There is an empty `<table>`. Since it's empty, you can remove it and everything will be vertically aligned middle.

Otherwise, if you really need that empty table, on your `<td>` you can put `style="vertical-aligm:top"`.