# material-ui: How to top the text in tablecell?

Tags: material-ui

I have googled for many hours to find a solution, but it seems to be very difficult to vertically align text within a tablecell. I am confused as to why they make the horizontal alignment easy, while the vertical alignment is that difficult.

```
<TableCell colSpan={2} align='center' vertical-align='top' > 
    <Typography  variant="h5" gutterBottom > 
        Task
    </Typography> 
</TableCell>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Alignment of text in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943166/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `TableCell` component from material-ui [doesn't provide such](https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/#tablecell-api) `vertical-align` prop, only `align`. To change vertical align of `TableCell` you have to pass a `style` prop (or a className), like that:

```
<TableCell colSpan={2} align="center" style={{ verticalAlign: 'top' }} > 
    <Typography  variant="h5" gutterBottom > 
        Task
    </Typography> 
</TableCell>
```

Any props that `TableCell` doesn't know [is passed to it's children root](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/TableCell/TableCell.js#L149) (`th` element in this case), and in [JSX you can pass a inline style](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) with the prop `style` and a camelcased object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sx prop. It's a shortcut for defining custom styles that has access to the theme.

```
<TableCell colSpan={2} align="center" sx={{ verticalAlign: 'top' }} > 
    <Typography  variant="h5" gutterBottom > 
        Task
    </Typography> 
</TableCell>
```