# positioning cell values in html table

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I have a table where which values in td tag are projecting more towards upside. I want the values inside that to be centered. I have tried this below code but it didn't work. Any way we can center the value in such a way that its not too up nor too down?

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Attach working snippet here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical Alignment of text in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943166/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this to the style, because text-align adds horizontal alignment

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

You can read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 1):

you can use line height

for example if your `<td>` height is 48px, give your `<td>` this css :

```
line-height : 48px;
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't know how is your css, but with this example it seems to work fine.

### DEMO (you can see "Canada" is placed correctly)

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars <br> <br> <br> <br> Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri Yoshi Tannamuri Yoshi Tannamuri Yoshi Tannamuri Yoshi Tannamuri Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "text-align" is the horizontal alignment.  What you need is the "vertical-align" property.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp